# Table - vertical centering

Tags: tables

Please, how can I center vertically all cells? Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|m{4.8cm}|m{3cm}|m{3.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
\centering Pozorovaný objekt &\centering Určená hodnota $E$ [keV] &\centering Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV] &\centering $FWHM$ [keV]&$NET$ \\ 

\hline
Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& \centering  $661,68 \pm 0,02$& \centering   $661,66$& \centering    $1,5$&$70096$\\
\hline
Poloha comptonovy hrany& \centering $478 \pm 4$&\centering  477,34 (shoduje se s teoretickou)&  &   \\
\hline
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu&\centering    $565 \pm 12$&\centering 554,58& &       \\
\hline
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu&\centering    $182 \pm 4$&\centering  184,32& &       \\

        \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \label{Cs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. This doesn't compile.

Comment: I am sorry, I editted the question.

Comment: They appear vertically centered on my screen when I compile this. Not on yours? Or are you just looking for a more efficient way of writing the code?

Comment: I think that these cells are not vertically centred. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK7nn.png  I would like to know a more efficient way of writing code, but primary I think that under yellow cells are spaces larger. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description in the comments, the following might do what you're looking for?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|m{4.8cm}|m{3cm}|m{3.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|}
        \hline
\centering Pozorovaný objekt &\centering Určená hodnota $E$ [keV] &\centering Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV] &\centering $FWHM$ [keV]&$NET$ \\ 

\hline
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& \centering  $661,68 \pm 0,02$& \centering   $661,66$& \centering    $1,5$&$70096$\\
\hline
Poloha comptonovy hrany& \centering $478 \pm 4$&\centering  477,34 (shoduje se s teoretickou)&  &   \\
\hline
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu&\centering    $565 \pm 12$&\centering 554,58& &       \\
\hline
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu&\centering    $182 \pm 4$&\centering  184,32& &       \\

        \hline
        \end{tabular}

    \label{Cs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Essentially, the lines `&&&&\\[-10pt]` just add a very narrow, empty line of cells where you want the extra padding. The `&&&&` makes sure that none of your vertical lines are cut. It's not super elegant, but it would probably generate the look that you're going for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposition with `tabularx`, to ensure the table does not overflows into the margin, and `makecell`, which lets you define a minimal vertical spacing at the topˆand bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs}
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}S{X}|>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}S{X}|>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}S{X}|Sc|Sc|}
        \hline
\centering Pozorovaný objekt & Určená hodnota $E$ [keV] & Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV] &\makecell{\emph{FWHM} \\{ [keV]}} & \emph{NET} \\
\hline
Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& $661,68 \pm 0,02$ & $661,66$& $1,5$ & $70096$ \tabularnewline
\hline
Poloha comptonovy hrany& $478 \pm 4$ & 477,34 (shoduje se s teoretickou) & & \\
\hline
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu & $565 \pm 12$& 554,58 & & \\
\hline
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu & $182 \pm 4$ & 184,32 & & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\label{Cs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. And this right side please?   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/enWC8.png

Comment: What is the problem exactly? I can see no difference with the image in my post.

Comment: I am sorry, I added wrong picture. I ment   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWo91.png

Comment: Did you change something in the code?

Comment: No. I have nothing changed.

Comment: Did you compile twice? Tabularx has some computations to do and the exact placement of cells and vertical rules may not be rthe definitive placement on first run.